What does IOCP APIs correspond to in Linux since Linux doesn't have anything like IOCP?
I was wondering about the relevance of IOCP-related APIs of .NET when it runs on Linux since Linux doesn't have anything like IOCP.
Linux simply uses the Epoll mechanism. So, what do the IOCP APIs correspond to in Linux?
For example, we can get the Worker and IOCP threads count using ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out workerThreads, out portThreads);
But what do the port threads correspond to in Linux?
